# cannot locate header while making buildworld in custom kernel source

Tags: kernel, freebsd, make

I'm trying to install a custom kernel in freebsd and here's step I followed:

1. install freebsd 9.1 on vm from the image
2. get the source from hardenedBSD (branch hardened/9/kernsep)
3. execute "make buildworld" from the source tree (/hardenedBSD)

at this point, make buildworld gave me an error that the compiler cannot locate "nk/nk_cpufunc.h" which the custom kernel declared in sys/cpufunc.h with #include . The error message was following:

```
In file included from /usr/home/realyuki/hardenedBSD/lib/libc/amd64/gen/getcontextx.c:35:
/usr/obj/usr/home/realyuki/hardenedBSD/tmp/usr/include/machine/cpufunc.h:42:27: error: nk/nk_cpufunc.h: No such file or directory
/usr/obj/usr/home/realyuki/hardenedBSD/tmp/usr/include/machine/cpufunc.h:43:25: error: sys/nk/vmmu.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/home/realyuki/hardenedBSD/lib/libc/amd64/sys/__vdso_gettc.c:33:
/usr/obj/usr/home/realyuki/hardenedBSD/tmp/usr/include/machine/cpufunc.h:42:27: error: nk/nk_cpufunc.h: No such file or directory
/usr/obj/usr/home/realyuki/hardenedBSD/tmp/usr/include/machine/cpufunc.h:43:25: error: sys/nk/vmmu.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/home/realyuki/hardenedBSD/lib/libc/stdlib/malloc.c:179:
/usr/obj/usr/home/realyuki/hardenedBSD/tmp/usr/include/machine/cpufunc.h:42:27: error: nk/nk_cpufunc.h: No such file or directory
/usr/obj/usr/home/realyuki/hardenedBSD/tmp/usr/include/machine/cpufunc.h:43:25: error: sys/nk/vmmu.h: No such file or directory
mkdep: compile failed
*** [.depend] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/home/realyuki/hardenedBSD/lib/libc.
*** [lib/libc__L] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/home/realyuki/hardenedBSD.
*** [libraries] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/home/realyuki/hardenedBSD.
*** [_libraries] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/home/realyuki/hardenedBSD.
*** [buildworld] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/home/realyuki/hardenedBSD.
```

I would appreciate any advices.